# Android - exclude HVGA devices from Google Play in Manifest

Tags: android, manifest, screen-resolution

I need to exclude HVGA (320x480) and smaller screen resolution devices from Google Play in the Manifest file. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Try this in your manifest: <supports-screens        
        android:smallScreens="false"/>

Comment: Already did - this didn't work.